# How to put the string in the JSON and get the value in Java

Tags: java, json, string, key

I want to get the value of String and I am trying to put the string in the JSON and get it. The format of string is `"key=value&key1=value"`. The code I am using is:

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(String);
String value = json.get("key").toString();
```

Comment: Don't revert other peoples edits especially if they improve formatting of your question. If you want to change something then that is OK, but what is the point of making your question wall of text instead of letting it be more readable?

Comment: I wasn't reverting. I was trying to approve but something got messed up. sorry about that and thank you.

Comment: looks like you went wrong i mean it should be stored as "key","value"  to retrieve desired..

Answer (score 2):

That string is url encoded not json formatted.

You can use a url decoder instead. Something like http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/utils/URLEncodedUtils.html might work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I used Patterns and Matchers and it worked perfectly. Thank you.